# Storing Numbers PIC ASM

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic

So, I know how to generate a random number when a button is pressed, but I am not sure how to store one number, let alone two, and then have it not go crazy when it's not in the button loop.
Here is my code now.

Sorry for the untidiness of it, don't know how to properly format it for this site.

```
#include <p16F690.inc>  
     __config (_INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF)  

    cblock  0x20  
Delay1                 
Delay2  
Display               
Num1  
Boolean  
Boolean2  
Boolean3  
Num2  
Num3  
LastStableState     
Counter  
    endc  

    org 0  
Start:  
    BANKSEL TRISA            
    movlw   0xFF  
    movwf   TRISA              
    movwf   TRISB            
    clrf    TRISC               

    BANKSEL ANSEL          
    clrf    ANSEL           
    BANKSEL PORTC              

    clrf    Display  
    clrf    Num1  
    clrf    Num2  
    clrf    Boolean  
    clrf    PORTC  
    movlw   1  
    movwf   Boolean  
    movwf   Boolean2  
    movwf   Boolean3  
    movwf   LastStableState    
    clrf    Counter   
MainLoop:  
    btfsc   LastStableState,0  
    goto    LookingForUp  
LookingForDown:  
    clrw                           
    btfss   PORTB,7           
    incf    Counter,w         
    movwf   Counter           
    goto    EndDebounce

LookingForUp:  
    clrw                      
    btfsc   PORTB,7          
    incf    Counter,w  
    movwf   Counter  

    incf    Display,f  

EndDebounce:  
    movf    Counter,w           
    ;xorlw  4  
    btfss   STATUS,Z       
    goto    Delay1mS  

    comf    LastStableState,f    
    clrf    Counter  
    btfss   LastStableState,0    
    goto    Delay1mS              


    btfsc   Boolean,0  
    goto    Num1Set  

    btfsc   Boolean2,0  
    goto    Num2Set  

    goto    Step3  



Delay1mS:  
    movlw   .02                  
    Call    Delay  
    goto    MainLoop  

Delay:  
    movwf   Delay2  
DelayLoop:       
    decfsz  Delay1,f  
    goto    DelayLoop  
    decfsz  Delay2,f  
    goto    DelayLoop  
    return                 

Num1Set:  
    movf    Display,w  
    movwf   Num1  
    movwf   PORTC  
    clrf    Boolean  
    goto    Delay1mS  

Num2Set:  
    movf    Display,w  
    movwf   Num2  
    movwf   PORTC  
    clrf    Boolean2  
    goto    Delay1mS  
Step3:  
    ;movf   Display,w  
    movlw   Num2  
    movwf   PORTC  
    goto    Delay1mS  
    ;andlw  Num1  
    ;movwf  PORTC  
    ;call   Delay1mS  
    ;goto   Start  
end
```

Comment: Highlight source code and click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: I think it did it by itself, but thank you I will do that next time 
or maybe that was you, now that I think about it

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to use assembler? If not, writing what you want in C is quite easy. Hand managing data in memories positions is cumbersome in ASM, in C you just need to declare the 2 variables to store your random numbers.

You can even keep your ASM functions, just wrap them (with the needed push, pop calls) so you can call it from a C context.